# Checkout page Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I'm using Magento 1.9.2 and I facing problem in my checkout page.

Deadlock and lock wait timeouts occur on more than 10 orders/sec.

Not sure what to do.

Can anyone help me to come out?